# Do minus sign in mysql table column names cause issues?

Tags: mysql

Do minus sign in table column names  effect performance or cause issues on some platforms or it is allowed or not?

```
 e.g. user-names 
 e.g  cpy-name
```

Comment: The dash character is not a valid character in an identifier. To use an identifier containing a dash character, the identifier must be properly escaped. An Identifier can be escaped by enclosing it in backtick ( `\`` ) characters....  `\`user-names\``. The identifier will need to be escaped *every* time it is referenced. A preferred pattern is to avoid using the dash character, and use an underscore character instead.  `user_names`,

Comment: Also take note of this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55556

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the names within back-ticks

```
CREATE TABLE `my-table` (
  `user-Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `epoch` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```