# Laravel - Arithmetical operation

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to calculate two columns values but I am receiving the following error. The Minus between invoice and payment is a arithmetical operation. Can you please help me.

**Controller.php**

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{
$this->data['balanceTotal'] = \DB::table('tb_accounts')->select('sum(invoice-payment)')->get();
return view('account.index',$this->data);
}
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
{{ $balanceTotal }}
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'sum(invoice-payment)' in 'field list' (SQL: select
>   `sum(invoice-payment)` from `tb_accounts`)

Comment: Do you have invoice-payment column in your table in DB ?

Comment: @NipunTyagi I have invoice and payment columns. Not invoice-payment column

Comment: See my answer. I updated this based on your comments

Answer (score 2):

You need a raw expression:

```
\DB::table('tb_accounts')->select(\DB::raw('sum(invoice)'))
```

But, I suppose you need to sum `invoice` and `payment`:

```
\DB::table('tb_accounts')->select(\DB::raw('(invoice - payment) AS amount'))
```

See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Note: avoid the `minus` in your column name or use back-ticks ([Do minus sign in mysql table column names cause issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510959/do-minus-sign-in-mysql-table-column-names-cause-issues/37511057))

Comment: Hi. Now it says Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Comment: I used as \DB::table('tb_accounts')->select(DB::raw('(invoice - payment) AS amount'))

Comment: It's better to import the namespace: `use DB;` if you're using the DB facade more than 1 time.

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; or use DB; ??

Comment: Both are possible ;-)

Comment: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/unive/public_html/sistem/resources/views/accounts/index.blade.php)

Comment: That's another error, caused in your blade file. I think it's better to start a new question for that case.

Comment: :)) Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the right answer if it did help you.

Comment: check my answer I've added psuedocode for your error.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
DB::table('tb_accounts')->select(\DB::raw('(invoice + payment) AS amount'))
```

You are getting this error 
`htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/unive/public_html/sistem/resources/views/accounts/inde‌​x.blade.php)`

because you are passing array in place of string if you need to pass array in your view try to return like this

```
return view('account.index')->withdata($data);
```

and then use in your `index.blade.php`

```
$data['balanceTotal'];
```